# combining array's but if "name" found combine/add the data

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to combine 2 arrays while adding the data if it exist, in javascript. I am not able to get it working. What i am trying to do is adding this array:

```
[  
   {  
  "name":"name1",
  "points":{  
     "intern":57,
     "extern":0,
     "total":57
  }
   },
   {  
  "name":"name2",
  "points":{  
     "intern":26,
     "extern":0,
     "total":26
  }
 }
]
```

With this one:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"name1",
      "points":{  
         "intern":31,
         "extern":0,
         "total":31
      }
   }
]
```

But if "name1" already is in the first array i want to add the intern and extern points so it would look like this:

```
[  
   {  
  "name":"name1",
  "points":{  
     "intern":88,
     "extern":0,
     "total":88
  }
   },
   {  
  "name":"name2",
  "points":{  
     "intern":26,
     "extern":0,
     "total":26
  }
 }
]
```

how am i able to do this in javascript?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You say "Im trying to combine 2 arrays while adding the data if it exist, in javascript." - so could you please show us the code that you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a name hashtable to find dupes:

```
 const hash = {}, result = [];

 for(const { name, points: {intern, extern, total}} of array1.concat(array2)) {
   if(hash[name]) {
     hash[name].intern += intern;
     hash[name].extern += extern;
     hash[name].total += total;
  } else {
     result.push(hash[name] = {name, intern, extern, total});
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the problem. Your code only works when i am removing the "points:{}" from the array but keeping the intern extern and total

Comment: @samir oops, how could i miss that? Whatever, i'll edit

Comment: Darn it! You missed it again :P. So i edited your second code and now its working (https://pastebin.com/5sdk3T4L). The new problem was that you tried to put the name inside the points so i moved it. If you edit your answer i will tag it as answered :)

Comment: @samir oh, im sorry :/